# Changing size of bubbles in bubble plot

Tags: python

I'm creating a bubble plot where every bubble represents a country.

My code looks like this:

```
from bubbly.bubbly import bubbleplot

figure = bubbleplot(dataset=df_subset1, x_column="GDP per capita (constant 2005 US$)", 

y_column="Fertility rate, total (births per woman)", 

bubble_column="CountryName", time_column="Year", color_column="CountryCode", 

x_title="GDP per capita", y_title="Fertility",

x_logscale=True, scale_bubble=3, height=650)

iplot(figure, config={'scrollzoom':True})
```

How can I change the size of the bubble?

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: @user1558604 Updated the code!